# Several threads for run render in Android 3D game. Thread-safe?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

For a long time I tried to make smooth animation for the application. And I got this solution: several threads launch draw frame of SceneRenderer:

```
public class OGLView extends GLSurfaceView {
  public void init(Context context, int versionGLES) {
    ...
    renderer = new SceneRenderer(context, versionGLES);
    setRenderer(renderer);
    ...
  }
}

public class SurfaceRunnable implements Runnable {
  ...
  @Override
  public void run() {
    while(true) {
      surfaceView.requestRender(); // draw frame
      if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) break;
    }
  }
}

public class SurfaceExecutor implements Executor {
  private List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();

  @Override
  public void execute(@NonNull Runnable runnable) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
    thread.setPriority(10);
    thread.start();
    threads.add(thread);
  }
  ...
}

public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private SurfaceExecutor executor = new SurfaceExecutor();
  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    ...
    SurfaceRunnable sr = new SurfaceRunnable(oglView);
    /* run four threads for SceneRender */
    executor.execute(sr); 
    executor.execute(sr);
    executor.execute(sr);
    executor.execute(sr);
    ...
  }    
}
```

As a result, the animation has become smoother. Long testing of the application did not lead to errors. Testing on different device configurations did not detect changes in the animation rate. Question: How much is this approach thread safe? All drawing and operations with matrices are done in SceneRenderer. Thank you all. Please, excuse my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a complete application it's impossible to say whether this is safe or not, as that entirely depends on what those 4 threads are doing and what resources are shared across them.

In all honesty though, this looks like a nasty hack. All 4 threads seem to be doing the same thing, any any fix of "just run 4 copies of the same thing and hope" seems to be running better by luck rather than any particular intentional design benefit.

Comment: Thanks! I agree with you. But this works for the current application. Maybe because due to several threads, the render is always in the foreground.